# How can I allow trailing slashes on some URLs without a redirect, but not on others?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Here's the scenario.

Assume I have a site, wordpress.site, which has the following Permalink structure: `/%postname%`

Assume I then set up the following posts:

- /post1
- /post2
- /post3

If someone were to type in "wordpress.site/post1/" (extra slash), Wordpress will automatically 301 redirect the user to "wordpress.site/post1".

So far so good.

But now, let's imagine that there's an old URL "/post4/", and for SEO reasons, I want to create a post for this URL ***and*** keep the trailing slash?

In other words:

- Calling wordpress.site/post4/ does not redirect to wordpress.site/post4 but
- Calling wordpress.site/post4, would redirect to wordpress.site/post4/ and
- Calling wordpress.site/post1 does not redirect, but
- Calling wordpress.site/post1/ would redirect to wordpress.site/post1

How would I go about achieving this?

I attempted to do it by using add_rewrite_rule(), but couldn't seem to achieve what I was after (I was still redirected, and yes, I did flush the rewrite rules). Sample code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite_func' );
function my_rewrite_func()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'post4/$', 'index.php?p=12', 'top' );
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use **[flush_rewrite_rules()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)**:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite_func' );
function my_rewrite_func() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'post4/$', 'index.php?p=12', 'top' );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

and / or whichever rewrite rules you use, you could always use `/?` for optional trailing slashes or [force the trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780859/htaccess-rewrite-to-force-trailing-slash-at-the-end) if you would prefer for it to always be there.

Answer (score 0):

i did not used it, but i heard a lot about this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/ which is precisely for that kind of situation. I you don't want to use a plugin, maybe a lot at the source code could lead you to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Simon, but this definitely doesn't do what I'm after. I think perhaps I haven't explained the question properly, I'll edit it to try and clarify.

Comment: Ok, so i'll try again ^^ Maybe you could use .htaccess and write some redirections rules ? If it's SEO, using `redirect permanent` could do the trick.